# DiscordJS volume command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to write a command to change the volume of the music being played, but each time the player and resource variables in the volume() function are empty while the bot normally plays the song. What can I do to make it work?

```
class music_cmd{
    constructor(client, message, prefix, cmd, args, generateDependencyReport, joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, ytdl){

        this.client = client;
        this.message = message;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.cmd = cmd;
        this.args = args;
        this.joinVoiceChannel = joinVoiceChannel;
        this.createAudioPlayer = createAudioPlayer;
        this.createAudioResource = createAudioResource;
        this.ytdl = ytdl;
        this.connection = null;
        this.players = new Map();

        if(cmd === 'play'){
            this.play();
        }

        if(cmd === 'volume'){
            this.volume();
        }

    }

    async play(){
        
        try{
            this.connection = await this.joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: this.message.member.voice.channel.id,
                guildId: this.message.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: this.message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
            });

            const stream = this.ytdl(this.args[1], { filter: 'audioonly' });
            
            const player = this.createAudioPlayer();
            const resource = this.createAudioResource(stream);

            this.players.set(this.message.guild.id, { player, resource });

            player.play(resource);
            this.connection.subscribe(player);
            this.message.channel.send('Rozpoczynam odtwarzanie utworu..');
        } catch(error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    volume(){
        const volume = parseInt(this.args[1]);
        if (isNaN(volume) || volume < 0 || volume > 100) {
        this.message.channel.send('Podaj poprawną wartość głośności (liczba od 0 do 100).');
        return;
        }

        const guildId = this.message.guild.id;
        const { player, resource } = this.players.get(guildId) || {};

        console.log(player);
        console.log(resource);

        if (!player || !resource) {
        this.message.channel.send('Nie odtwarzam żadnej muzyki.');
        return;
        }

        resource.volume.setVolume(volume / 100);
        this.message.channel.send(`Głośność ustawiona na ${volume}%.`);
    
    }

}

export default music_cmd;
```

I've tried everything to fix it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your volume() method the issue seems to be that the player and resource variables are not being properly retrieved from the players map. This could be due to incorrect access or the players map not being populated correctly.

```js
this.players.set(this.message.guild.id, { player, resource }); 

const playerData = this.players.get(guildId);

const { player, resource } = playerData;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. After changing the code with the implementation of your advice, I get the following error:
file:///home/wiewior/music/music_cmd.js:60
        const { player, resource } = playerData;
                ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'player' of 'playerData' as it is undefined.